# Do you need to call super.prepareForSegue:?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, swift3

I am following the Apple Books for learning. I am currently working with table view and segues. I got this piece of code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    
    guard segue.identifier == "saveUnwid" else {return}
    
    let symbol = symbolTextField.text ?? ""
    let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
    let description = descriptionTextField.text ?? ""
    let usage = usageTextField.text ?? ""
    emoji = Emoji(symbol: symbol, name: name, description: description, usage: usage)
}
```

The only thing I do not understand is why they call `super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)`.

The code is contained into a object of UITableViewController and the segue leads back to a table view with a list of Emoji objects.

Comment: That is weird. The Apple docs specifically state "The default implementation of this method does nothing." - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare

Perhaps it is considered best practice to always call super.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need to call super in this case because the default implementation of this method (which would be in the super class) does nothing

> The default implementation of this method does nothing.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare